# Cmake compiler error ANN library not found

Tags: cmake

I tried to compile this repository [link](https://github.com/FrankMoosmann/FranksVelodyneAlgos) but I am stuck with CMake Error: **ann_LIBRARIES** not found. While searching in the inernet I found ANN [link](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/Files/1.1.2/ann_1.1.2.tar.gz) which I build but I don't know how to give the absolute path in Cmake file. And also I installed libflann1.9 and libflann-dev but still I am having the same problem.

I have ubuntu 18.04 and qt5, boost lib, blas & lapack and libpng libraries are installed.

```
cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   serialization
--   filesystem
--   system
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for module 'libxml++-2.6'
--   Found libxml++-2.6, version 2.40.1
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so   
-- Found GLUT: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so  
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   chrono
--   system
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Found PNG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (found version "1.6.34") 
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   thread
--   system
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   thread
--   serialization
--   program_options
--   regex
--   system
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   regex
--   system
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   system
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   regex
--   system
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
ann_LIBRARIES
    linked by target "TrackingUtils" in directory /home/dhiren/Dev/FranksVelodyneAlgos/libTrackingUtils

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/dhiren/Dev/FranksVelodyneAlgos/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/dhiren/Dev/FranksVelodyneAlgos/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Thank you

Comment: "I don't know how to give the absolute path in Cmake file." - Add option to `cmake` which sets given variable `-Dann_LIBRARIES=/path/to/lib`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Oh man this trick is working but I got the warning "WARNING: Target "visTracks" requests linking to directory "/home/dhiren/Downloads/ann_1.1.2".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item."

Comment: In my previous comment `path/to/lib` is an absolute path of the **file**, not a *directory*. It should be like `/home/dhiren/Downloads/ann_1.1.2/libann.so`.

Comment: I couldn't find libann.so instead I have libANN.a inside lib folder

Comment: Then use path to that file as a value of the variable. Again, it should be a path to the **file**, not to the *directory* containing that file.

Comment: Yeah I did so, but after that, I ended up with same error while compiling, I am not sure  whether this approach fixed the problem or not. Thank you

Comment: "I ended up with same error while compiling" - Which error? The only **error** you have described is about unset `ann_LIBRARIES` variable. After setting this variable you shouldn't have such error any more.

Comment: After building sucessfully while performing **make** command I get `error: ANN/ANN.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ANN/ANN.h> // (approximate) nearest neighbor - for feature matching ` although I have ANN.h file in /home/ann_1.1.2/include/ANN/ANN.h

Comment: Well, the project is ready for non-system `ann` library, but it is not ready for non-system headers for that library (it has `find_library` call, for which you can specify your library, but it has no corresponded `find_path` call, where you can specify location of the headers.)

Comment: Now got resolved by putting absulute path `#include </home/ann_1.1.2/include/ANN/ANN.h>`

Comment: is there any way to put ANN dynamic path, I know nothing about who c++ or c works.. sorry for that .. Thank you

Comment: You may add `include_directories("/home/ann_1.1.2/include")` line to the [libTrackingUtils/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/FrankMoosmann/FranksVelodyneAlgos/blob/master/libTrackingUtils/CMakeLists.txt)

Comment: It was such a pain in my ass, I don't know why Auther had missed this library to mentioned. Thank you very much, you helped me a lot for my research. Finally it worked

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to compile the codebase

My procedures are given follows:

1. First I tried to compile the source code in ubuntu 18.04 but got stuck with so many errors, so I tried in ubuntu 14.04 (docker).
2. I installed the required packages as the author mentioned.
3. Now I stuck with ann_LIBRARIES problem, so for that, I downloaded ANN library from [link](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/Files/1.1.2/ann_1.1.2.tar.gz) and build by simply performing **make linux-g++** from inside ann_1.1.2 folder
4. Now ANN library is ready to use. After that to avoid the ann_LIBRARIES problem while building process, we should perform command from terminal `cmake -Dann_LIBRARIES=/home/ann_1.1.2/lib/libANN.a ..`
5. Now so far I build the project sucessfully. Now time to compile the code using `make` command, again I got `ANN/ANN.h: No such file or directory` error which I resolved by giving absulute path `#include </home/ann_1.1.2/include/ANN/ANN.h> //approximate) nearest neighbor` from each file where the error arose. Obviously providing absolute path is not a good idea. That's it

Thanks to @Tsyvarev

Hope this will help somebody.